# Problem converting numpy array to ctypes array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I'm having a problem converting a numpy array to a ctypes array. I don't get any errors or exceptions, but the ctypes array is completely different from the original array.

```
def convarray(x):
    arr = x.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint64) )
    print(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
    print(x.shape, x.dtype, x)
    ...
```

The result of the print statements is:

> 8 399 1099526307842
> (958150,) uint64 [ 8  8  8 ... 92 94 96]

As you can see, of the first three elements, only one is correct.

Why is this happening?

I am using Numpy 1.21.0 with Python 3.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was: the array being passed as x was derived by slicing from a 2d array, and thus its underlying data was 2 dimensional as well. Setting `x = x.copy()` solved the problem by creating a new array with 1 dimensional data.